# questions about Android Oreo build

Tags: android-8.0-oreo, android-build

I want to test something on Android Oreo now.
And I am building on Ubuntu-18.04, target is AVD.

Below is what I did.

```
$ sudo apt-get install git-core gnupg flex bison build-essential zip curl zlib1g-dev gcc-multilib g++-multilib libc6-dev-i386 lib32ncurses5-dev x11proto-core-dev libx11-dev lib32z1-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libxml2-utils xsltproc unzip fontconfig

$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-8.1.0_r33
$ repo sync -c -j $(($(nproc)-2)) --no-tags --no-clone-bundle
$ repo start android-11.0.0_r28 --all
```

source was received without error.

```
$ . build/envsetup.sh
including device/asus/fugu/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/car/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/mini-emulator-arm64/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/mini-emulator-armv7-a-neon/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/mini-emulator-mips/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/mini-emulator-mips64/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/mini-emulator-x86/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/mini-emulator-x86_64/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/uml/vendorsetup.sh
including device/google/dragon/vendorsetup.sh
including device/google/marlin/vendorsetup.sh
including device/google/muskie/vendorsetup.sh
including device/google/taimen/vendorsetup.sh
including device/huawei/angler/vendorsetup.sh
including device/lge/bullhead/vendorsetup.sh
including device/linaro/hikey/vendorsetup.sh
including sdk/bash_completion/adb.bash


$ lunch sdk_phone_x86_64-userdebug

============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=8.1.0
TARGET_PRODUCT=sdk_phone_x86_64
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_PLATFORM_VERSION=OPM1
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=x86_64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=x86_64
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=x86
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=x86_64
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-5.4.0-66-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=OPM1.171019.012
OUT_DIR=out
AUX_OS_VARIANT_LIST=
============================================

$ m

...
When executed as above, the following error occurs.

[  0% 116/83904] Lex: applypatch <= bootable/recovery/edify/lexer.ll

FAILED: out/target/product/generic_x86_64/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libedify_intermediates/lexer.cpp
/bin/bash -c "prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/flex/flex-2.5.39 -oout/target/product/generic_x86_64/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libedify_intermediates/lexer.cpp bootable/recovery/edify/lexer.ll"
flex-2.5.39: loadlocale.c:130: _nl_intern_locale_data: Assertion `cnt < (sizeof (_nl_value_type_LC_TIME) / sizeof (_nl_value_type_LC_TIME[0]))' failed.
[  0% 120/83904] Ensuring Jack server is installed and started
FAILED: setup-jack-server
/bin/bash -c "(prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin install-server prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-launcher.jar prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-server-4.11.ALPHA.jar  2>&1 || (exit 0) ) && (JACK_SERVER_VM_ARGUMENTS=\"-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+TieredCompilation\" prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin start-server 2>&1 || exit 0 ) && (prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin update server prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-server-4.11.ALPHA.jar 4.11.ALPHA 2>&1 || exit 0 ) && (prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin update jack prebuilts/sdk/tools/jacks/jack-4.32.CANDIDATE.jar 4.32.CANDIDATE || exit 47 )"
Jack server already installed in "/home6/.jack-server"
Communication error with Jack server (35), try 'jack-diagnose' or see Jack server log
SSL error when connecting to the Jack server. Try 'jack-diagnose'
SSL error when connecting to the Jack server. Try 'jack-diagnose'
[  0% 141/83904] target  C++: bugreportz <= frameworks/native/cmds/bugreportz/bugreportz.cpp
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
16:03:55 ninja failed with: exit status 1
```

I did the following work additionally through google.

```
$ ./prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin kill-server
$ ./prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin start-server
Launching Jack server java -XX:MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=-1 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp /home6/.jack-server/launcher.jar com.android.jack.launcher.ServerLauncher
```

After opening another terminal, I rebuild, but I am getting the same error.
I would really appreciate if someone could help me in solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

works for me

Comment: Please add explanation by editing your answer